# why is std::condition_variable::notify_one blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, poco-libraries, condition-variable

For some reason the call signal.notify_one() blocks the current thread and doesn't return. I have never heard about this behavior and I don't know how to resolve it.

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
  _exit = true; // _exit is a std::atomic<bool> 
}

std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
_signal.notify_one();
std::cout << "after" << std::endl;

_thread.join();
```

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 and the code above is called during destruction.

I hope you can point me in the right direction, thank you much for your help!

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the code snippet above from a callback? Can you include code that is waiting for the notification? Also, a small point, you don't need `_exit` to be `std::atomic` given that it is protected by `_mutex`.

Comment: A call to `notify_one` may awaken a thread that had called `_signal.wait()`, which is where your code may be. Consider adding breakpoints after your `_signal.wait()` to see if that's where your code returns to

Answer (score 6):

Okey, I finally was able to find the problem. To give a bit of background, I'm currently using some Poco libraries (see http://pocoproject.org/) and I implemented my own Poco::Channel. After some digging I realized that Poco keeps all channels in a **static** LoggingRegistry which is only freed after all remaining threads have been killed.

My best guess is that a *std::condition_variable* becomes invalid if a thread is killed that is waiting on that *std::condition_variable*.

Anyway, in order to prevent the issue, one has to call the following before the `main(int argc, char** argv)` returns:

```
Poco::Logger::shutdown();
Poco::LoggingRegistry::defaultRegistry().clear();
```

Comment: Good on you for posting your findings.  Might be good to edit the question title and tags to help other Poco users (and fewer non-Poco users) find the question....

Comment: I think this answer is a prime candidate for why oversimplifying your question to the point where it lacks all relevant details is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar behavior in an embedded environment. Depending on how the condition_variables are implemented in your OS, the notifying thread might implicitly wait for the notified thread.

If your notified thread has a very low priority and is blocked from running for a while,  the call to notify_one() might block as well, until the system has time to schedule the low prio task.