# Worker threads, running in a DLL gets killed, on application shutdown, before one can gracefully shutdown them

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, dll

I, for some reason, need to have a global object in a .dll, which manages a `std::thread`. It is implemented in a following way:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class Foo
    {
public:
    Foo () : m_closeThread (false)
        {
        m_thread = std::thread (&Foo::ThreadProc, this);
        }

    ~Foo ()
        {
            {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (m_mutex);
            m_closeThread = true;
            }

        m_cv.notify_one ();
        m_thread.join ();
        }

private:
    void ThreadProc ()
        {
        while (true)
            {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (m_mutex);
            m_cv.wait (lock, [this] () { return m_closeThread; });
            if (m_closeThread)
                break;
            }
        }

private:
    bool m_closeThread;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    };

Foo& GetFoo ()
    {
    static Foo foo;
    return foo;
    }

extern "C" void Function ()
    {
    auto& foo = GetFoo ();
    }
```

However, when, the application is closed, **before** the `~Foo` is executed, all worker threads, of the .dll, get killed, or as the output window of MSVS2015 says:

> The thread 0x1040 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

And, due to this fact ([Source0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107778/why-is-stdcondition-variablenotify-one-blocking), [Source1](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/8ld5nw/stdcondition_variablenotify_one_blocking_on/)), the application blocks on `m_cv.notify_one ();` call, if one uses Windows 7 (doesn't block on Windows 8 and above).

The fact, that it blocks on one particular version of Windows, while not on others, makes me think, that some sort of UB is to blame (such as DLL unload ordering related issue, since such issue is not reproducible if such object is not in a .dll), but I fail to think of solution, that allows me to gracefully shutdown the thread, while having the object global (since, one would need to do major application restructuring, to make it not global).

So, can one shutdown the thread gracefully, before it is killed by the Windows platform?

**Side note 0:**

For the sake of example completeness,

**this is the DLLMain:**

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID) { return TRUE; }
```

**This is the Header of the .dll:**

```
#pragma once
extern "C" void Function ();
```

**This is the Console application, that uses said .dll:**

```
#include "..\Test\Header.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main ()
    {
    Function ();
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (2s);
    }
```

**Side note 1:**

I am, currently limited to using, at most, C++11 (or, whatever functionality is present in MSVS 2015).

Comment: Local static `Foo foo;` makes this code flawed. You have no control over object lifetime and rely on dynamic lazy initialization and dynamic uninitialization. You should write a dedicated init / uninit methods that must be called prior to using any of the library's function for the first time / after using any of the library functions for the last time. Another problem is that you have potentially throwing "C" function.

Comment: @VTT Local static gets initialized upon first usage of such object, which is to defer the initialization until we, absolutely, need it (even if it wasn't local `static`, but global one, one would run into issues of starting a thread, when DLL didn't, yet, initialize). And, it's global so once initialized, it would run until the application is closed. Having separate uninitialization routine, _might_ be possible, but I need to investigate the feasibility of it, in the actual code. What I try to learn, with this question, is why the worker threads get killed, before objects are destructed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `WinMain` returns, the runtime calls [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess). The first thing that does is "1. All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread, terminate their execution without receiving a `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notification."